# Text element name not appearing in ListLayoutElements

Tags: arcpy, layouts, element

As in the title, I have the simple below code:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"U:"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"U:RAFT.mxd")
layoutlist = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "")

print layoutlist
```

Which gives me:

```
[<TextElement object at 0x23ddb50[0x15325228]>, <TextElement object at 0x23dd990[0x1531c548]>, <TextElement object at 0x15311570[0x1531c570]>, <TextElement object at 0x15311bd0[0x15325340]>, <TextElement object at 0x23ddb30[0x153252a0]>, <TextElement object at 0x15311710[0x1531c6d8]>]
```

Which lists the Text Elements in the mxd as expected. However, I have given one text element a name as it is the specific one I want to work with. My assumption was that element name should appear in the list? How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The cryptic "names" of each text element you see in the list, such as `<TextElement object at 0x23ddb50[0x15325228]>` is just a pointer to a memory address and not the actual name of the text element you give within a map document.

To be able to list the names of a text element, you'd need to use its [`name` property](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/textelement-class.htm) as below:

`[elem.name for elem in layoutlist]`

Sometimes you want to find a particular text element by its name, for instance, to change its position or text. You could do this by checking the name of each text element present as below:

`text_elem_to_work_with = [elem for elem in layoutlist if elem.name == 'elem_name_to_search'][0]`

This would give you a single `TextElement` you can inspect or mutate as needed.